# query properties of an object with linq

Tags: linq, attributes, query-optimization, propertyinfo

I want to scan a type for it's properties and the annotated attributes and return an object with the following structure

```
public class PropertyContext
{
    public object PropertyValue { get; set; }

    public object SourceType { get; set; }

    public Attribute Annotation { get; set; }
}
```

I have this query

```
var query = from property in _target.GetType().GetProperties()
            from attribute in Attribute.GetCustomAttributes(property, true)
            select new PropertyContext
            {
                Annotation = attribute,
                SourceType = _target,                                            
             };
```

This is executed deferred so i only generate the `PropertyContext` while the calling method needs them.

---

Now i want to fill the `PropertyValue` property of the `PropertyContext` object.

To get the value of the property i have have a call to an other component like this

```
_propertyValueAccessor.GetValue(_target, property)
```

My question is, how i can modify the query in a way that 
*

- the value is only read once
- but only if a PropertyContext is created

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about:

```
var query = from property in _target.GetType().GetProperties()
            let attributes = Attribute.GetCustomAttributes(property, true)
            where attributes.Any()
            let val = _propertyValueAccessor.GetValue(_target, property)  
            from attribute in attributes
            select new PropertyContext
            {
                PropertyValue = val,
                Annotation = attribute,
                SourceType = _target,
            };
```

Comment: Wonderfull, thats the way i want.